# What happens to Mars after the apocalypse?

Tags: futurama

in the episode "Farewell to arms" after the end of the world of 3012 that hit Mars, what happened to the planet?

Comment: Your question was asked on the Futurama Live Q&A event! That means you win a prize package from Stack Exchange. Please contact me at brett at stack exchange dot com with your shipping address to claim your prize. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much. First, I live in Italy and I do not know if this affects shipping. second I'd like to know what I won?

Comment: Italy is totally fine, doesn't affect shipping. Please email me at brett at stack exchange dot com and I can give you more details then!

Comment: Perfect, my email address is saretta12@live.it.

Answer (score 6):

As answered in the Futurama live spot (http://www.ustream.tv/recorded/23929909/highlight/275846) 48:31.

It returned to it's original orbit.

Comment: Link is dead. Any chance of finding it again?